# VBA code to color cells of columns in array and a different color of columns not in array

Tags: excel, vba

I have limited familiarity with VBA, but I've come across the following code. Unfortunately, its functionality is only partially successful. Help is appreciated.

Within my Excel worksheet, there are numerous named columns (names reside in the usual location, row 1).
The objective is as follows: based on a cell-value, "varia" in a column named "Type," the cells in the columns that are specified in an array will receive an interior color of RGB(192, 222, 230).
This aspect of the code works as intended.

Some of my numerous columns which are not covered in the array are labeled such as "Regular Price"  "Tax class"  "Tax Status"  "Images" etc.
Based on the same cell-value, "varia", the cells in these columns should receive an interior color of RGB(255, 0, 0) (as indicated in the code under the line `Dim additionalCell As Range`).
The issue here is that these cells remain uncolored.

I am hesitant to create a second pre-defined array for the many remaining columns.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim typeColumn As Long
    typeColumn = Application.Match("type", Rows(1), 0)

    If IsError(typeColumn) Then Exit Sub ' "type" column not found

    Dim ColumnNames As Variant
    ColumnNames = Array("sku", _
            "short description", _
                        "url slug", _
                        "status", _
                        "categorieën", _
                        "tags", _
                        "Attribute 1 global", _
                        "Attribute 1 visible", _
                        "Attribute 1 name", _
                    "Attribute 1 value(s)", _
                    "Attribute 1 default", _
            "Weight (kg)")

    Dim ColumnIndices As Collection
    Set ColumnIndices = New Collection

    Dim colName As Variant
    Dim ColIndex As Long

    ' Populate the ColumnIndices collection with column names and their indices
    For Each colName In ColumnNames
        On Error Resume Next
        ColIndex = Application.Match(colName, Rows(1), 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ColIndex > 0 And ColIndex <> typeColumn Then
            ColumnIndices.Add ColIndex
        End If
    Next colName

    If ColumnIndices.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub ' No valid columns found

    Application.EnableEvents = False ' Disable events to prevent recursive triggering

    Dim c As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    ' Validate the Target range
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.UsedRange) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Intersect(Target, Me.UsedRange)
            On Error Resume Next

            If cell.Column = typeColumn Then
                Dim typeValue As String
                typeValue = Left(cell.Value, 3)

                ' Color specified columns based on the "varia" condition
                For Each colName In ColumnNames
                    ColIndex = Application.Match(colName, Rows(1), 0)
                    If ColIndex > 0 And ColIndex <> typeColumn Then
                        Set c = Cells(cell.Row, ColIndex)
                        If Left(cell.Value2, 5) = "varia" Then
                            c.Interior.Color = RGB(192, 222, 230) ' Light blue
                        Else
                            c.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone ' Clear interior color
                        End If
                    End If
                Next colName

                ' Color additional columns in red
                Dim additionalCell As Range
                For Each additionalCell In Rows(1).Cells
                    If Not IsError(Application.Match(additionalCell.Value, ColumnNames, 0)) _
                    And additionalCell.Column <> typeColumn Then
                        Set c = Cells(additionalCell.Row, additionalCell.Column)
                        If Left(additionalCell.Value2, 5) = "varia" Then
                            c.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red
                        Else
                            c.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone ' Clear interior color
                        End If
                    End If
                Next additionalCell
            
            End If

            On Error GoTo 0
        Next cell
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True ' Re-enable events
End Sub
```

Comment: Why did you not want to do this with conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0):

I put my changes with "**".
I actually learned something valuable from your code, especially the part where you used Application.Match to search for a string in the ColumnNames array. Thanks!

```
' Color additional columns in red
                Dim additionalCell As Range
                '** limit cells within the used range
                For Each additionalCell In Me.UsedRange.Rows(1).Cells

                    '** change if condition
                    If IsError(Application.Match(additionalCell.Value, ColumnNames, 0)) _
                       And (additionalCell.Column <> typeColumn) Then
                        Debug.Print additionalCell.Value
                        '**Set c = Cells(additionalCell.Row, additionalCell.Column)
                        Set c = Cells(cell.Row, additionalCell.Column)
                        '**If Left(additionalCell.Value2, 5) = "varia" Then
                        If Left(cell.Value2, 5) = "varia" Then
                            c.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red
                        Else
                            c.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone ' Clear interior color
                        End If
                    End If
                Next additionalCell
```

Answer (score 0):

### Highlight Specific Columns in a Matching Row

[image]

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Define constants.

    Const HEADER_ROW_INDEX As Long = 1 ' row of the (used) range
    Const CRITERIA_HEADER As String = "Type"
    Const BEGINS_WITH As String = "Varia"
    Dim HighlightColumns() As Variant: HighlightColumns = Array( _
        "sku", _
        "short description", _
        "url slug", _
        "status", _
        "categorieën", _
        "tags", _
        "Attribute 1 global", _
        "Attribute 1 visible", _
        "Attribute 1 name", _
        "Attribute 1 value(s)", _
        "Attribute 1 default", _
        "Weight (kg)")
    Dim HIGHLIGHT_COLOR As XlRgbColor: HIGHLIGHT_COLOR = RGB(192, 222, 230)
    Dim OTHER_COLUMNS_COLOR As XlRgbColor: OTHER_COLUMNS_COLOR = vbRed

    ' Reference the intersecting cells ('icrg') of the criteria column.

    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Me.UsedRange
    If rg.Rows.Count = 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data
    
    Dim hrg As Range: Set hrg = rg.Rows(HEADER_ROW_INDEX)
    
    Dim cCol As Variant: cCol = Application.Match(CRITERIA_HEADER, hrg, 0)
    If IsError(cCol) Then Exit Sub ' criteria column not found
    
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = hrg.Cells(cCol) _
        .Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)

    Dim icrg As Range: Set icrg = Intersect(crg, Target)
    If icrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no intersection with criteria column
    
    Dim rOffset As Long: rOffset = rg.Row
    
    ' Reference the matching header cells ('mhrg').
    
    Dim mcIndexes As Variant:
    mcIndexes = Application.Match(HighlightColumns, hrg, 0)
    If Application.Count(mcIndexes) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no headers found
    
    Dim mhrg As Range, mcIndex As Variant, c As Long
    
    For c = 1 To UBound(mcIndexes)
        mcIndex = mcIndexes(c)
        If IsNumeric(mcIndex) Then
            If mhrg Is Nothing Then
                Set mhrg = hrg.Cells(mcIndex)
            Else
                Set mhrg = Union(mhrg, hrg.Cells(mcIndex))
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    
    ' Highlight.
    
    Dim irrg As Range, imrg As Range, iccell As Range, irOffset As Long

    For Each iccell In icrg.Cells
        irOffset = iccell.Row - rOffset
        Set irrg = rg.Rows(irOffset + 1)
        If InStr(1, CStr(iccell.Value), BEGINS_WITH, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            irrg.Interior.Color = OTHER_COLUMNS_COLOR ' All
            iccell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone ' Criteria
            Set imrg = mhrg.Offset(irOffset)
            imrg.Interior.Color = HIGHLIGHT_COLOR ' Highlight
        Else
            irrg.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone ' All
        End If
    Next iccell
  
End Sub
```